# nlm number of function evaluations per iteration?

Tags: r, timing, hessian, nlm

I use nlm to maximize a likelihood in R. I would like to predict the number of likelihood evaluations and abort if the task is likely to take too long. nlm returns the number of 'iterations' (typically 10-20), and I take it that each iteration involves one numerical evaluation of the Hessian. Time for each iteration (Hessian?) depends on the number of parameters. So I'd like to know: What is the general relationship between the number of parameters and the number of function evaluations per iteration in nlm?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general, and so is my answer.

From the reference of `nlm`:

> If the function value has an attribute called gradient or both
>   gradient and hessian attributes, these will be used in the calculation
>   of updated parameter values. Otherwise, numerical derivatives are
>   used. deriv returns a function with suitable gradient attribute and
>   optionally a hessian attribute.

If you provide the gradient and the Hessian for a function being minimized, each iteration involves two function evaluations. If you don't, the Hessian and the gradient are calculated numerically. The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/optimize.c). As far as I understand, the parameters of the R `nlm` function only affect the number of iterations until convergence, but have no influence on the way gradients are evaluated numerically.

Comment: To be clear, I am evaluating the gradients numerically, and 'number of parameters' is the length of the parameter vector p.